# WLResourceRequest is not defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have created a sample project where I am trying to hit a service which gives the Latitude and Longitude of a particular location. I have already deployed the adapter on the server and now I am trying to hit the adapter. When I try to do so, I get the error: WLResourceRequest is not defined in my js. Following is my code:

```
function locate() {

    var locat = document.getElementById('location').value;
    alert(locat);

    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
            "/adapters/LocationAdapter/getGmapLatLng",
            WLResourceRequest.GET
    );

    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['110064']");

    resourceRequest.send().then(
            function(response) {
                alert("Success\n\n" + response);
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("Failure\n\n" + error);
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Is this a Cordova app ? Which platform are you trying on? 
Please specify the version of MobileFirst you're using. Also, ensure that you have added a reference to worklight.js in your html page

Comment: 1) Its a MFP 8.0 project.
2) I am on Android Emulator.
3) I cannot find worklight.js because in MFP 8.0, you get a cordova project and you have to include the mfp plugin.

Comment: If the worklight.js is not seen, then your plugin is not installed or not properly installed. Try removing and adding it again

Answer (score 0):

Add mfp plugin properly. If already added then remove it and add again.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp`

Answer (score 0):

In your Config.xml:
Define the plugin like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mfp" spec="8.0.2016101414"/>
```

then run the following command:

```
cordova prepare android
or
cordova platform remove android && cordova platform add android
```